# 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 = 2018

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Add the four basic operators × ÷ + −:
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 to get the total 2018. 
Keep the order; do not combine numbers.
Don't use any brackets.
Use all four operators at least once.

Comment: "do not add [...] numbers" Surely you mean "concatenate", not "adding" (using the + symbol)

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, it must be clear now, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's better.

Comment: I think your intent is clear enough, but "do not combine numbers" prohibits the use of multiplication, addition, etc. @Lolgast's suggestion to use the word *concatenate* is much better.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a Python script and made sure these are the only solutions:

> $10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2*1 = 2018$
>  
>  $10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2/1 = 2018$

Here's the Python code I wrote to solve this puzzle:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python3
>
> o=["+","-","*","/"]
> op=[0]*9
>
> def con():
>     n = ""
>     for i in range(10, 0, -1):
>         n = n + str(i) + (str(o[op[10-i]]) if i > 1 else "")
>     return n
>
> def f(n):
>     if n == 9:
>         s = con()
>         if eval(s) == 2018:
>             print(s + " = " + str(eval(s)))
>     else:
>         for i in range(4):
>             op[n] = i
>             f(n+1)
>
> f(0)
> ```

Comment: That's good. What's rationale on like these problems?

Comment: Nicely done - not sure you need the .0 though

Comment: @CalvT븃 The codes are outputs from the script.

Comment: @iBug I doubt hiding the code is necessary - it does not immediately show any solutions, at most the way you could arrive at them, but it would also take a bit of effort understanding it. If people want to do that, they wouldn't really mind a spoiler block either. Also, you should be able to put code in there using regular spoiler blocks and the pre and /pre tags at the start and end.

Comment: Or you may post the code at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) for example.

Comment: @Lolgast I posted the code directly.

Comment: Very well. I made a separate version (though I have pretty much the same code as in your con), only using `itertools.product("+-*/",repeat=9)` which simplifies the f(n) quite a bit. I get the same answers.

Comment: I wonder what the first year is that we won't be able to form it with these 10 numbers.

Comment: @Bachrach44 See my answer. Turns out, for this specific rule set, we only need to endure next year, and then nothing for a long long time!

Comment: If these answers are the only two that exist, then there are no solutions for 2018 because you haven't used the minus symbol at least once, failing the "Use all four operators at least once" criterion.

Answer (score 4):

To answer [Bachrach44](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2501/bachrach44)'s comment on [iBug](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44061/ibug)'s answer, here are all the solutions my script has found so far for the years 2000 onward:

> ```
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3-2-1=2013
>
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3-2*1=2014
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3-2/1=2014
>
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3-2+1=2015
>
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2-1=2017
>
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2*1=2018
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2/1=2018
>
> 10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2+1=2019
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2-1=2238
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2*1=2239
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2/1=2239
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2+1=2240
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2-1=2242
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2*1=2243
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2/1=2243
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2+1=2244
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2-1=2256
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2*1=2257
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2/1=2257
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2+1=2258
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2-1=2260
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2*1=2261
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2/1=2261
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2+1=2262
>
> 10*9*8*7*6/5/4*3/2-1=2267
> 10*9/8*7*6/5*4*3*2-1=2267
>
> 10*9*8*7*6/5/4*3/2*1=2268
> 10*9*8*7*6/5/4*3/2/1=2268
> 10*9/8*7*6/5*4*3*2*1=2268
> 10*9/8*7*6/5*4*3*2/1=2268
>
> 10*9*8*7*6/5/4*3/2+1=2269
> 10*9/8*7*6/5*4*3*2+1=2269
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2-1=2327
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2*1=2328
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2/1=2328
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3-2+1=2329
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2-1=2331
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2*1=2332
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2/1=2332
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5*4/3+2+1=2333
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4-3/2-1=2356
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4-3/2*1=2357
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4-3/2/1=2357
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4-3/2+1=2358
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4+3/2-1=2359
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4+3/2*1=2360
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4+3/2/1=2360
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5-4+3/2+1=2361
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4-3/2-1=2364
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4-3/2*1=2365
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4-3/2/1=2365
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4-3/2+1=2366
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4+3/2-1=2367
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4+3/2*1=2368
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4+3/2/1=2368
>
> 10*9/8*7*6*5+4+3/2+1=2369
>
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2455
>
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2456
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2456
>
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2457
>
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2459
>
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2460
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2460
>
> 10-9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2461
>
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2510
>
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2511
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2511
>
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2512
>
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2514
>
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2515
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2515
>
> 10-9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2516
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2-1=2520
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2*1=2521
> 10-9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2/1=2521
>
> 10-9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2+1=2522
>
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2526
>
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2527
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2527
>
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2528
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2528
>
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2529
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2529
> 10+9*8*7*6*5/4/3*2-1=2529
> 10+9*8*7/6*5*4*3/2-1=2529
>
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2530
> 10+9*8*7*6*5/4/3*2*1=2530
> 10+9*8*7*6*5/4/3*2/1=2530
> 10+9*8*7/6*5*4*3/2*1=2530
> 10+9*8*7/6*5*4*3/2/1=2530
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2530
>
> 10+9*8*7*6*5/4/3*2+1=2531
> 10+9*8*7/6*5*4*3/2+1=2531
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2531
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2531
>
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2532
> 10-9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2532
>
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2533
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2533
>
> 10+9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2534
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2-1=2538
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2*1=2539
> 10+9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2/1=2539
>
> 10+9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2+1=2540
>
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2544
>
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2545
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2545
>
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2546
>
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2548
>
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2549
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2549
>
> 10+9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2550
>
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2599
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2599
>
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2600
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2600
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2600
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2600
>
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2601
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2601
>
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2603
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2603
>
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2604
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2604
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2604
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2604
>
> 10+9*8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2605
> 10*9-8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2605
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2-1=2609
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2*1=2610
> 10*9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2/1=2610
>
> 10*9+8*7*6*5/4*3*2+1=2611
>
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2-1=2615
>
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2*1=2616
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2/1=2616
>
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3-2+1=2617
>
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2-1=2619
>
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2*1=2620
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2/1=2620
>
> 10*9+8+7*6*5*4*3+2+1=2621
> ```

Note that they always come in groups of 3 with the middle one having twice as many possibilities, which makes sense: You'll always end in either -1, *1, /1 or +1, which result in x-1, x, x and x+1, respectively. These are (should be at least) all the solutions up to the year 2710, I guess that'll do for a while. Based on these results, we could get a question like this next year, then not get any for over 2 centuries, and then we should prepare for a truckload of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

> $10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2*1$

Comment: The solution, or A solution? Did you prove it's the only one? (just curious)

Comment: Is there a solution with all four operators using at least once? (I mean using "-")

Comment: Since we're not allowed to use brackets, i don't think there is a solution using all four operators.

Comment: @Jack See my answer, it's likely not.

Answer (score -1):

For 2019 it's:

> 10∗9∗8∗7/6/5∗4∗3+2+1

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This was not what was asked, but maybe you want to post a new question with this as a solution?